How Zero Padding a sequence affects its Discrete Cosine Transform(DCT)?
When I take an input sequence d[0] to d[3], take FFT of that I found D[0] to D[3]. If I zero pad that sequence (D[0],..,D[3],0,0,0,0) and take IFFT, I can see that final output vector x represents an interpolated version of the original input sequence d[n] which can be explained by sinc interpolation. My question is, can the similar phenomena expected with DCT and IDCT? When I try to do this in MATLAB, I could not find any interpolated pattern in the output vector after taking IDCT. Is there any explanation to this?
However, it seems that the last values of input vector are same, then the last values for final output x also approaches a constant value. Thus, there seems to be some relations between d and x. But can anyone give any idea how can I mathematically explain this?
